# Why is my react app, which has a node and mysql backend, working locally but not on Heroku?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, heroku

The home route for the initial request is "http://localhost:5000/contacts". After deploying to heroku, the UI is rendered but the data is not and I'm getting a status of 404: not found. The url shown is this one: "https://powerful-gorge-20271.herokuapp.com/contacts". I am using the Clear-DB add on on heroku as my mySql database. I have tried modifying the proxy in the react app's package.json file from "http://localhost:5000" to the heroku url but that does not work. The repo for this app is: https://github.com/aosante/React-Contact-Manager

I used this article https://daveceddia.com/deploy-react-express-app-heroku/ for guidance but it still doesn't work

This is the code in the app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const app = express();

//Static file declaration
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

//production mode
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile(path.join((__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html')));
  });
}

app.use(cors());

const SELECT_ALL_CONTACTS = `SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY firstName ASC`;

//Connection creation to mysql database
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'host goes here',
  user: 'user goes here',
  port: 'goes here',
  password: 'password goes here',
  database: 'heroku_cdf7d751774d818',
  insecureAuth: true
});



 connection.connect(err => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});

//Server start
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  connection.query(SELECT_ALL_CONTACTS, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      return res.json({
        data: results
      });
    }
  });
});

app.get('/api/contacts', (req, res) => {
  connection.query(SELECT_ALL_CONTACTS, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      return res.json({
        data: results
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post('/api/contacts/add', (req, res) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, email, phone } = req.query;
  const INSERT_CONTACT = `INSERT INTO contacts (firstName, lastName, email, phone) VALUES ('${firstName}', '${lastName}', '${email}', '${phone}')`;
  connection.query(INSERT_CONTACT, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      return res.send(results);
    }
  });
});

app.delete('/api/contacts/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const DELETE_CONTACT = `DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id = ${id}`;
  connection.query(DELETE_CONTACT, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      return res.send(results);
    }
  });
});

app.get('/api/contacts/edit/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const GET_CONTACT = `SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = ${id}`;
  connection.query(GET_CONTACT, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      return res.json({
        data: results
      });
    }
  });
});

app.put('/api/contacts/update/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { firstName, lastName, email, phone } = req.query;
  const UPDATE_CONTACT = `UPDATE contacts SET firstName = '${firstName}', lastName = '${lastName}', email = '${email}', phone = '${phone}' WHERE id = ${id}`;
  connection.query(UPDATE_CONTACT, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(results);
    }
  });
});

//production mode
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join((__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html')));
  });
}

//this goes in the end after all the requests
//build mode
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/public/index.html'));
});
```

And this is what's in the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "react-contact-manager",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple contact manager with mysql backend",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build - -prefix client"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "mysql"
  ],
  "author": "Andrés Osante",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  }
}
```

I also added a Procfile with "web:node app.js" written on it but that didn't help

Comment: We need to see what you have tried to help you out. Be sure to read more on "How To Ask" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also search for related questions. I think you will find this question has been asked before or at least one's like it. But here is a great article on this subject that might help you. If it doesn't edit your question with specific things you have attempted and what is failing: https://daveceddia.com/deploy-react-express-app-heroku/

Comment: Yes I used that same article as guidance but the problem seems to be with the request to the mysql database. I can't say what I have tried because I don't even know what to try.. And yes similar questions have been asked but none of them have worked for me

Comment: Give us some more of your code, without linking to your repo. What scripts are in your package.json? What other files are you using to tell heroku what to do with your app?

Comment: Ok I've updated the question and added the relevant code

Comment: Edit your post quick, you posted private connection data, such as passwords. You don't want that public.

Comment: I edited database credentials immediately. It's been almost a week and I still haven't figured this out, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things. The ordering of routes is important in Express--It's first come, first serve.

Since in production, you capture all your routes `app.get('*',` to serve your front-end, the other routes can never be hit. You need to move this toward the end of `app.js` after declaring your other routes.

Also, you should carefully define your routes so that there is no collision between the front and back end. I'm not sure if you are using `React Router` or not, but you define a get route on the root of your application (`'/'`). This will conflict with your front-end. This seems to be doing the same thing as `/contacts`, so go ahead and remove the root definition.

I'm not sure, personally, perhaps someone else can add, but in `package.json` in your `scripts`, consider redefining `heroku-postbuild`. I'm not sure what changing the directory might do to the app, maybe nothing. But here is another way of handling this:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

Comment: This is not directly related to the question, but very important. Your app is open to SQL Injection attacks since you are not validating or escaping data on your server before running your queries. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values

Comment: It works! I realized the routing issue beforehand (sorry for no updating my post), but that wasn't it. I believe the issue was in the fact that the app.get(*) route inside the production mode conditional, was first. And yes, I'm aware of the injection issue. I didn't use any sort of ORM or validation as you pointed out. I just wanted to test deploying a react app with some sort of backend (I'm a beginner as you can tell :)). Anyhow, thank you for your help and advice!